# Card column layout

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

First off, I am new to css / wordpress etc so not very experienced.

I need help with card layouts. I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyfC7.jpg) to have the same layout as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2np9.jpg), as in I want the cards to be in 2 columns instead of a 1. Messed around with the code a lot and can't seem to get it...

Would post pastebins but <10 rep so can't post >2 links.

EDIT: see comments for pastebins and more info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Place your code in fiddle/codepen and share with us. We can help you with the issue if you show a working demo.

Comment: All the cards are generated using php so wouldn't help. Pastebins: [1 column page](http://pastebin.com/MVXLA4gh), [2 column page](http://pastebin.com/5cNWPatt), [CSS doc](http://pastebin.com/PfKMQ0QA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i tell you we need your code sample to help you.

I will explain how to do it with bootstrap framework

You can have something like this:

```
<div>Business Strategy</div>
<div>Boosting Company</div>
<div>How High Growth...</div>
<div>Uk Company Dashboard</div>
```

You have to import the bootstrap CDN you can get it on this link:

> http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

After that you will apply a colum grid in the clases of your divs and surround all of them in a "row" div it will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" >Business Strategy</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Boosting Company</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">How High Growth...</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Uk Company Dashboard</div>
</div>
```

With that classes you are telling the browser that the divs will be displayed as full width when the screen viewport is less than 700px and half width when the viewport is higher.

This is the easyest way for begginners, I recommend you to read the bootstrap tutorial on W3CSchools it will help your first steps in the resposives frameworks

> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Here is the explanation about why you should use that classes

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi there thanks for your answer. Here is the code: Pastebins: [1 column page](http://pastebin.com/MVXLA4gh), [2 column page](http://pastebin.com/5cNWPatt), [CSS doc](http://pastebin.com/PfKMQ0QA)
So I think I am already using the bootstrap format. The issue I have is that I am using `<div class="col-sm-6.....` for both the layouts yet it comes out differently when displayed - hence why I am confused. I have now been able to get [this](http://i.imgur.com/lEtqvPg.png) by removing both `<div class="container">` and `<div class="row">`

Comment: Comment continued: but as you can see it is still not quite right (cards now stretched to width of page and background behind the cards is now the same as the footer background). Any ideas...? Sorry, I am a beginner at all of this.

Comment: The container element encapsulates all content and centers it on the center of your screen also probably its providing your old background, so i guess you wont want to remove it, the row element its just for clear both sides of the element. I saw your code and i tell you the options that came to my mind:
- If you are working with wordpress, try to navigate in the wp-admin/plugins, maybe you can find some option that suit your needs.
-If you want to use that code, you will have to investigate it in depth, you have +1500 css lines with medias and responsive stuff, its more than probable that..

Comment: some lines are crashing with your new clases, use the ctrl+f and watch how your elements behaves.